# A little confused about a way to compromise security in the book "How tomcat works" chapter 2

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

[How tomcat works online book from gitbook](https://www.gitbook.com/book/l-webx/how_tomcat_works/details)
Chapter 2 mentions a way to compromise security:

> There is a serious problem in the first application. In the ServletProcessor1 class's process method, you upcast the instance of ex02.pyrmont.Request to javax.servlet.ServletRequest and pass it as the first argument to the servlet's service method. You also upcast the instance of ex02.pyrmont.Response to javax.servlet.ServletResponse and pass it as the second argument to the servlet's service method.

```
try {
    servlet = (Servlet) myClass.newInstance();
    servlet.service((ServletRequest) request,
    (ServletResponse) response);
}
```

> This compromises security. Servlet programmers who know the internal workings of this servlet container can downcast the ServletRequest and ServletResponse instances back to ex02.pyrmont.Request and ex02.pyrmont.Response respectively and call their public methods. Having a Request instance, they can call its parse method. Having a Response instance, they can call its sendStaticResource method.

can anyone give me an example, how this will compromises security. Let's say i have a Servlet Application on this HttpServer1, How can another programmer do any harm to my servlet application?

Comment: As the book explained, by writing another servlet **in** your application. Which makes this a bit of a red herring IMO. If the attacker can add code to your application, they can do all of those things without your code.

Comment: The book describes Tomcat 4 and 5. It is therefore at least ten years out of date, whatever its other merits and demerits may be. There isn't any actual need for the upcasts mentioned. It isn't at all clear what the author is actually talking about. Find a better book.